# Where is CM's Appollo's favorite playlist stored, can I export it?

Tags: backup, music, music-player

I've been using CM's Apollo as music player and it's doing it's work perfectly, but i'd like to export my favorites (play)list to my PC.
With BlueMuze i can export my self made playlists in .m3u format to SD which works great, but the favorites playlist doesn't show up in BlueMuze because of the fact that either it's location is somewhere else-, or it is saved in another format. I think the favorites list is just a playlist like any other playlist, so then the solution would be very simple, duplicate it and place it in the location next to the other playlists. The point is that i have no clue where Apollo stores it playlists.
I have found a file 'favorites.db' in /data/data/com.andrew.apollo/databases
which contains all my favorites, but other playlists are stored somwhere else.
If i know where, it might be the solution to my problem.
I was hoping you guys could help me with this, i'd be very thankful!

Cheers

Edit: there's ample info about how to export playlists, but thats not the case here since a music players favorites list is not a standard playlist. playlist export apps can't find/recognize this list, so please don't mark this as duplicate, thankyou

Comment: Apollo doesn't seem to maintain its own private playlist. I don't know what method it uses but the playlist ends up in a database of Media Storage. The database is at `/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db`. You can find the name and id of the playlist under the table "audio_playlists - (View)". In the table  `audio_playlists_map` would the  content of  all the playlists. The content can be sorted using a particular playlist's ID. // I've never exported a playlist but it should be easy now. I'll try to find an easy way in the mean time.

Comment: This app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ssi.playlistbackup&hl=en claims to take backup of system playlist. Try it out.

Comment: @Firelord yeah i came across that location, so that means multiple playlist would be merged into one external.db file unfortunately. I have some low-level basic knowledge about databases and sql but i have no idea how to extract a list of songs to create a playlist from.. :(  would be awesome if you could help me with that! I have tried the app you mentioned, aswell as BlueMuze which does the same, but it can't find/recognize the favorites list

Comment: Don't worry about going into low level. The link for the app I posted in my second comment would do the job. That app will find the playlist and will give you the option to save them.

Comment: @Firelord it indeed does the job well for self created playlists, but the favorites list doesn't appear among those playlists. Maybe i could merge the favorites.db with the that external.db to make it a regular playlist, but i doubt if i can manage that. Do you think that's possible?